# Free Graph Database with Java querying and updating

Tags: java, database, graph, owl, ontology

I am looking for a free Graph Database which (obviously) runs constantly.
Furthermore, I want to run a Java Application(I would write this myself) with an interface that allows me to query or update or insert things from/to the database in real time, if possible with SPARQL.

The database should be compatible with OWL and RDF.

I have tried Janosgraph, Neo4J and GraphDB free, but so far I have failed to get them to work properly.

I had spent quite some hours looking for tutorials or examples on how to connect to the database and then run some queries, but I failed. Perhaps it is just me, but I found that the documentation was quite poor on this specific context.

Maybe someone here can help me or point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful!

Cheers.

Comment: Questions asking for a software are off-topic here. This should be asked at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Apache Jena Framework.

Comment: Okay thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Assumed that it's still kind of code related as, apparently, it is possible to use the mentioned programmes to achieve what I want to but fail to do.   I have tried to use the Jena framework but I wasn't aware of the fact that it can be used as a database? I thought it creates an instance during runtime but is closed after exiting the application. I want to have a database that runs all the time

Comment: Search for triple stores. There are a lots of...and  failing with setting up GraphDB sounds strange - the documentation is simple and complete. It is pretty trivial. The same holds for other like Jena Fuseki, Virtuoso, etc.

Comment: And Jena TDB is a triple store. Jena Fuseki is the HTTP layer on top of it. Documentation is online and always your friend.

Comment: By the way, the term *graph database* is much broader than RDF triple store!

Comment: okay cheers, I will have a look into it!

Comment: Regarding Ontotext GraphDB see the [answer to a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098996/writing-to-ontotext-graphdb-using-jena/51100227#51100227). I have also created an complete reading/writing example at [Getting started with Ontotext GraphDB](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/06/29/getting-started-with-ontotext-and-jena/).

Comment: Thanks for the two helpful links! Slowly making progress